# advise for safely using remote client without exhausting ports

Tags: c++, windows, client, port, winsock2

I am working on a remote client program for Windows that sends data from a sensor unit to a server application over ethernet / internet connection. The client logs into the server with a username and password. Per the protocol the client then sends data one way to the server without ever expecting a response from the server. All works fine untill the wireless internet connection at a client gets broken. In my first version of the client I retried making a connect attept each loop but very often would run out of ports as Windows standard timeout was 4 minutes. I tried changing one client the other day. I set Windows registry to "TcpTimedWaitDelay" to 1 and rewrote the client app to close its socket on error then wait 1 second before attempting a reconnect. This seemed to be working but I did loose that client for a while today. I can't be certain if the wireless went down for the whole time it was offline or not.
I'm looking for advise on a good method when using this type of client that can be used reliably. Is there another way to prevent port exhaustion within the application code or is modifing Windows registry almost always needed? I can add pieces of my code but I have gone over my code itself in a recent question here. I'm looking for a more broad suggestion here.

```
void checkConnect(NTRIP& server)
{
time_f functionTime = getTimePrecise();
//1st check for recv or gracefully closed socket
char databuf[SERIAL_BUFFERSIZE];
fd_set Reader, Writer, Err;
TIMEVAL Timeout;
Timeout.tv_sec = 1; // timeout after 1 seconds
Timeout.tv_usec = 0;
FD_ZERO(&Reader);
FD_ZERO(&Err);
FD_SET(server.socket, &Reader);
FD_SET(server.socket, &Err);
int iResult = select(0, &Reader, NULL, &Err, &Timeout);
if(iResult > 0)
{
    if(FD_ISSET(server.socket, &Reader) )
    {
        int recvBytes = recv(server.socket, databuf, sizeof(databuf), 0);
        if(recvBytes == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            cout << "socket error on receive call from server " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
            closesocket(server.socket);
            server.connected_IP = false;
        }
        else if(recvBytes == 0)
        {
            cout << "server closed the connection gracefully" << endl;
            closesocket(server.socket);
            server.connected_IP = false;
        }
        else  //>0 bytes were received so read data if needed
        {
            cout << "received " << recvBytes << " bytes of data" << endl;
        }
    }
    if(FD_ISSET(server.socket, &Err))
    {
        cout << "ip thread select returned socket in error group" << endl;
        closesocket(server.socket); //what if dont close this socket, leave open for another loop
        server.connected_IP = false;
    }
}
else if(iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    cout << "ip thread select returned SOCKET_ERROR " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    closesocket(server.socket);
    server.connected_IP = false;
}
//2nd check hard disconnect
if(server.connected_IP == true && functionTime - timer_send_keepalive >= 15.0)
{
    timer_send_keepalive = functionTime;

    char buf1[] = "hello";
    cout << "checking send for error" << endl;

    iResult = send(server_main.socket, buf1, sizeof(buf1), 0);
    if(iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        int lasterror = WSAGetLastError();
        if(lasterror == WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
        {
            cout << "server send WSAEWOULDBLOCK" << endl;
        }
        else if(lasterror != WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
        {
            cout << "server testing connection send function error " << lasterror << endl;
            closesocket(server.socket);
            server.connected_IP = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "sent out keep alive " << iResult << " bytes" << endl;
    }
}//end send keep alive
}
```

send function

```
bool sendData(CHAR_MESSAGE& data)
{
bool check = false;
if(data.flag_toSend == true)
{
    if(WaitForSingleObject(data.mutex, 0) != WAIT_FAILED)
    {
        if(server_main.connected_IP == true)
        {
            int iResult = send(server_main.socket, data.buffer, data.bufferLength, 0);
            if(iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                int lasterror = WSAGetLastError();
                if(lasterror == WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
                {
                    cout << "main server send WSAEWOULDBLOCK" << endl;
                    check = false;
                }
                if(lasterror != WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
                {
                    cout << "server main send error " << lasterror << endl;
                    closesocket(server_main.socket);
                    server_main.connected_IP = false;
                    check = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                check = true;
                server_main.lastDataSendTime = getTimePrecise();
                //{cout << "sent data to main   server" << endl;}
            }
        }
        if(server_backup.connected_IP == true)
        {
            int iResult = send(server_backup.socket, data.buffer, data.bufferLength, 0);
            if(iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                int lasterror = WSAGetLastError();
                if(lasterror == WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
                {
                    cout << "backup server send WSAEWOULDBLOCK" << endl;
                    //check = false;
                }
                if(lasterror != WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
                {
                    cout << "server backup send error " << lasterror << endl;
                    closesocket(server_backup.socket);
                    server_backup.connected_IP = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                server_backup.lastDataSendTime = getTimePrecise();
                //{cout << "sent data to backup server" << endl;}
            }
        }
        data.flag_toSend = false;
        ReleaseMutex(data.mutex);
    }//end obtained mutex
}//end data flag to send is true

return check;
}
```

login function

```
bool loginServer(NTRIP& datasource )
{
std::string sLogin = buildLogin(datasource);
char databuf[1030];

int iResult = send(datasource.socket, sLogin.c_str(), sLogin.length(), 0);
if(iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    cout << "Send error = " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    closesocket(datasource.socket);
    return false;
}
else  //not socket error
{
    int flags = 0;
    fd_set Read, Err;
    TIMEVAL Timeout;
    FD_ZERO(&Read);
    FD_ZERO(&Err);
    FD_SET(datasource.socket, &Read);
    FD_SET(datasource.socket, &Err);
    Timeout.tv_sec = 1;
    Timeout.tv_usec = 0;
    iResult = select(0, &Read, NULL, &Err, &Timeout);
    if(iResult == 0)
    {
        cout << "loginServer function, select timeout" << endl;
        closesocket(datasource.socket);
        return false;
    }
    else if(FD_ISSET(datasource.socket, &Read) )
    {
        int recvBytes = recv(datasource.socket, databuf, sizeof(databuf), flags);
        if(recvBytes == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            cout << "loginServer function, Error recv call  " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
            closesocket(datasource.socket);
            return false;
        }
        else if(recvBytes == 0) //server closed connection
        {
            cout << "loginServer function, server reclosed connection" << endl;
            closesocket(datasource.socket);
            return false;
        }
        else if(recvBytes > 0)  //process response
        {
            std::string tempString;
            for(int n=0; n<recvBytes; n++)
            {
                tempString += databuf[n];
            }
            if(tempString.compare(CONNECT_OK) || tempString.compare(HTTP_OK) )
            {
                cout << "server connected" << endl;
                return true;
            }
            else if(tempString.compare(ERROR_1))
            {
                MessageBox(NULL, ERROR_1, "NTRIP connect Error", MB_OK);
                closesocket(datasource.socket);
                return false;
            }
            else if(tempString.compare(ERROR_2))
            {
                MessageBox(NULL, ERROR_2, "NTRIP connect Error", MB_OK);
                closesocket(datasource.socket);
                return false;
            }
            else if(tempString.compare(ERROR_3))
            {
                MessageBox(NULL, ERROR_3, "NTRIP connect Error", MB_OK);
                closesocket(datasource.socket);
                return false;
            }
            else if(tempString.compare(ERROR_4))
            {
                MessageBox(NULL, ERROR_4, "NTRIP connect Error", MB_OK);
                closesocket(datasource.socket);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    else if(FD_ISSET(socket, &Err) )
    {
        cout << "loginServer function, select call error" << endl;
        closesocket(datasource.socket);
        return false;
    }
}//end not socket error on send login
closesocket(datasource.socket);
return false;
}
```

open a new socket

```
bool clientOpenSocket_connectServer(SOCKET& Socket, const char* serverADDR, const char* serverPORT)
{
int check;

if(Socket != INVALID_SOCKET)  //if not closed then close socket
{
    closesocket(Socket);
    Socket = INVALID_SOCKET;
}
time_f timer = getTimePrecise();

while(getTimePrecise() - timer < 5.0){} //wait 5 second before reconnect attempt
//set Windows reg to 1 second TcpTimedWaitDelay

ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family   = AF_INET;  //use IPv4
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
hints.ai_flags    = AI_PASSIVE;
//get socket memory address info
check = getaddrinfo(serverADDR , serverPORT, &hints, &result);
if ( check != 0)
{
    printf("Winsock getaddrinfo failed. %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    return false;
}
//prepare socket, sets IP4 or IP6, sock type and protocol used
for(ptr=result; ptr!=NULL; ptr=ptr->ai_next)
{
    Socket = socket( result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (Socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Socket failed initializing %d %d.\n", Socket, WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo (result);
        return false;
    }
    //now have a valid socket
    check = ioctlsocket(Socket, FIONBIO, &NonBlock);
    if (check == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("client socket could not set nonblocking, with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(Socket);
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        return false;
    }
    //set sockets to no-linger on close
    char value = 0;
    check = setsockopt( Socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_DONTLINGER, &value, sizeof( value ) );
    if (check == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "client socket could not set options no-linger " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    }
    //disable nagle algorithym
    if(disableNagleSockets == true)
    {
        value = 1;
        check = setsockopt( Socket, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &value, sizeof( value ) );
        if (check == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            cout << "client socket could not set options  " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        }
        else{cout << "Nagle Sockets set disabled" << endl;}
        value = 0;
        check = setsockopt( Socket, IPPROTO_TCP, SO_SNDBUF, &value, sizeof( value ) );
        if (check == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            cout << "client socket could not set options  " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        }
    }
    //attempt connect
    cout << "attempting connect" << endl;
    check = connect(Socket, ptr->ai_addr, ptr->ai_addrlen);
    if(check == SOCKET_ERROR )
    {
        check = WSAGetLastError();
        if(check == WSAEWOULDBLOCK) // then set a timeout
        {
            fd_set Write, Err;
            TIMEVAL Timeout;
            int TimeoutSec = 10; // timeout after 10 seconds
            FD_ZERO(&Write);
            FD_ZERO(&Err);
            FD_SET(Socket, &Write);
            FD_SET(Socket, &Err);
            Timeout.tv_sec = TimeoutSec;
            Timeout.tv_usec = 0;
            check = select(0, NULL, &Write, &Err, &Timeout);
            if(check == 0)
            {
                printf("connect call to server, select call timeout elapsed\r\n");
                closesocket(Socket);
                freeaddrinfo(result);
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                if(FD_ISSET(Socket, &Write) )
                {
                    freeaddrinfo(result);
                    cout << "socket opened to server, after wait" << endl;
                    return true;
                }
                if(FD_ISSET(Socket, &Err) )
                {
                    printf("connect call to server, select call error state\r\n");
                    closesocket(Socket);
                    freeaddrinfo(result);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        else if(check == WSAECONNREFUSED)
        {
            cout << "no server program at requested address " << serverADDR << endl;
            closesocket(Socket);
            freeaddrinfo(result);
            return false;
        }
        else if(check == WSAEHOSTDOWN || check == WSAETIMEDOUT)
        {
            cout << "no server present at requested address " << serverADDR << endl;
            closesocket(Socket);
            freeaddrinfo(result);
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "connect call WSA error code " << check << endl;
            closesocket(Socket);
            freeaddrinfo(result);
            return false;
        }
    }//end socket error
    //else instant connection is good
    cout << "socket opened to server" << endl;
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    return true;
}//end search for a socket address to use
freeaddrinfo(result); //no socket opened here
return false;
}//end of setup TCP port
```

So as of now it waits 5 seconds snce the last failed connection before attempting another. My earlier version tried a new connection each loop untill it connected. It seems right now that it may be working with the 5 second delay and setting Windows registry to close a port after 1 second.

Comment: Running this code and watching netstat I found the following occured. Each time the connection was broken the new connection port was incremented from the prior port number. When Windows reached the upper end of the available user port numbers it simply stopped allowing a connection to occur untill a certain local clock time when it appears all ports get reset by the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Use the connection until it breaks, and then create another one.

If it breaks so often that you encounter port exhaustion you have a network problem, not a programming problem.

If you get a connect error you should sleep for increasing amounts of time on each failure, e.g. 1,2,4,8,... seconds.

Comment: Thats what the client does but in my first version trying to open a port and connect each time the thread loops caused port exhaustion in less than a second due to Windows OS default time to close the ports. Thats why on the second version I limited it to 1 attept per second and editted the Windows registry.

Comment: I have found that at 12:00pm local PC clock time that Windows resets all of the ports, as all disconnected clients will reconnect to the server at that time. I have not found this documented anywhere. Win XP, Vista, 8.1.

Comment: 'Trying to open a port and connect each time' is the exact opposite of what I said. Do read what I wrote.

Comment: I have read what you wrote. Are you suggesting that I do not close the socket when the connect function returns a socket error state? Perhaps you have not read the specifics of what I wrote?

Comment: 'Connect each time' suggests to me that you're using a new connection per send, rather than using the same one until it breaks. As does the fact that you are evidently still encountering port exhaustion. I have no means of knowing what you mean other than from what you say. At this stage you need to post some code.